# OpenCV C++, videoCapture does noes not properly handle video (avi) with alpha channel

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture, avi, rgba

still learning openCV, but I've at least managed to find documentation on how to split a video (.avi) - with an alpha channel - into frames using openCV 2.4.13, C++, and using videoCapture().

I previously used the command line tool, FFMPEG, to split and save the avi in question into frames (.png) so that I could check whether or not the RGBA data from each frame in my C++ code matched up with the saved split frame RGBA - the idea is to not have to write the frames to disk, but rather work with just the RGBA data - which is why I'm not just using FFMPEG on the command line.

Here is the code I have so far, I explain my findings at the bottom:

```
void extract_frames(string& videoFilePath) {
    vector<Mat> frameVec;

    //open the video file
    VideoCapture cap(videoFilePath); // open the video file
    if (!cap.isOpened())  // check if we succeeded
        CV_Error(CV_StsError, "Can not open Video file");

    Mat frame;
    for (int frameNum = 0; frameNum < getFrameCountFromAVI(videoFilePath.c_str()); frameNum++)
    {
        cap >> frame; // get the next frame from video      
        frameVec.push_back(frame);
    }


    for (int spltF = 0; spltF < frameVec.size(); spltF++) {

        // converting frameVec[spltF] to RGBA
        // values when trying to read frameVec[spltF]c directly did not match up with image 
        // not sure why ????  - maybe its the modified pixels / I had the wrong coordinates 
        uchar* dstRgBA = new uchar[ ((Mat)(frameVec[spltF])).total() * 4];
        uchar* camData = new uchar[ ((Mat)(frameVec[spltF])).total() * 4];
        Mat continuousRGBA( ((Mat)(frameVec[spltF])).size(), CV_8UC4, camData);
        cv::cvtColor( ((Mat)(frameVec[spltF])), continuousRGBA, CV_BGRA2RGBA, 4);


        for (int i = 0; i < ((Mat)(frameVec[spltF])).rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < ((Mat)(frameVec[spltF])).cols; j++) {
                int index = (i*((Mat)(frameVec[spltF])).cols + j) * 4;

                // copy while converting to RGBA order
                uchar r = continuousRGBA.data[index + 2];
                uchar g = continuousRGBA.data[index + 1];
                uchar b = continuousRGBA.data[index + 0];
                uchar a = continuousRGBA.data[index + 3];

                dstRGBA[index + 0] = r;
                dstRGBA[index + 1] = g;
                dstRGBA[index + 2] = b;
                dstRGBA[index + 3] = a;             
            }
        }
        .... do stuff with dstRGBA ....
    }
+}
```

When debugging, I seem to get the correct RGB (it might be BGR) values at the respective pixel, but it seems that the alpha (A) is always coming up as 255, I'm really hoping the issue is my code and not the limitations of OpenCV.

I'm currently also looking at alternatives, like ffmpeg/libavcodec and C++ - but that is turning out to be a bit more difficult - given that documentation isn't as good as I had hoped.

If any one has any suggestions/ideas/examples/fixes - that would be more than helpful :)